# Slim: pretty and ugly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

In the [article](http://sephinrothcn.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/slim-vs-haml-performance-perspective/), which explains difference in performance perspective of rails template engines I find `slim pretty` and `slim ugly` terms. Can you explain difference between this?

Comment: can't give examples of "pretty" and "ugly" code because it's primarily opinion based.  Edited your question to focus on the other part, which we can answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like Slim uses [Temple](https://github.com/judofyr/temple) for template compilation. Temple provides the [`set_default_options`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/temple/Temple/Mixins/DefaultOptions#set_default_options-instance_method) method to Slim::Engine, documented and explained [here](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#default-options).

The corresponding Temple code that does the 'pretty' transformations (tab indentations and reordered attributes) to the compiled HTML appears to be here: https://github.com/judofyr/temple/blob/master/lib/temple/html/pretty.rb

I presume ugly just refers to having the pretty option set to false. The article you referenced is comparing performance, so the relevance of the pretty option to performance appears to be that the extra processing increases the overhead when generating HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Its just the way the resulting html is rendered:

- pretty: indentations are clean and easy to follow, useful for development mode
- ugly: everything is dumped without tabs, shorter (but difficult to read), ideal for production